# Arraylist method clarification

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

- So I am learning Arraylist concept from Java Collections from
  Javatpoint.com. I am currently studying the following method :
  boolean add(E e). Here, the return type of method is boolean , that
  is, either true/false. But , the explanation given for this method is
  as follows : It is used to append the specified element at the end of
  a list. I am following the below example : import java.util.*;

  `public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(); //Creating arraylist`

  ```
       list.add("Ravi");   //Adding object in arraylist  
       list.add("Vijay");    
       list.add("Ravi");    
       list.add("Ajay");    //Invoking arraylist object   
       System.out.println(list);}`
  ```

  **Output:** [Ravi, Vijay, Ravi, Ajay]

  ***My Doubt:***  The method says that it should return a boolean, instead, it returns the contents of the list. Can someone please
  clarify my doubt.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value returned by `list.add()`, so what makes you think it returns the contents of the list?

Comment: Just use `System.out.println(list.add("some string"));`, to see what the method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boolean value means it would return true if collection was changed after the method call otherwise false.

You can access that value like this,

```
boolean isAdded = list.add("Vijay");
```

You are getting all elements because you have printed the list object `System.out.println(list);`, which would call `toString()` method on that object.

It is not because of `add()`